# Allow NULL or create univerified user

Tags: database, database-design, null, foreign-keys

I am developing web application that allows users to post from a registered account or anonymously. Should I allow `NULL` in the `UserId` column in the `Post` table or create an unverified `User` and reference their id for unregistered users?

## Unverified User

**User**

```
| UserId | Name       |
+--------+------------+ 
| 1      | Unverified |
| 2      | Real User  |
```

**Post**

```
| PostId | UserId | Post           |
+--------+--------+----------------+
| 1      | 1      | Blah blah...   |
| 2      | 1      | Blah blah...   |
| 3      | 2      | Blah blah...   |
```

## - VS -

## Allow `NULL`

**User**

```
| UserId | Name       |
+--------+------------+ 
| 1      | Real User  |
```

**Post**

```
| PostId | UserId | Post           |
+--------+--------+----------------+
| 1      | NULL   | Blah blah...   |
| 2      | NULL   | Blah blah...   |
| 3      | 1      | Blah blah...   |
```

Answer (score 0):

It's usually considered good practice to not rely on NULL's to represent meaning; I would probably use a 0 or 1 to represent an anonymous user.  It's easier to search as well; you don't have to keep switching between IS NULL or = depending on whether or not you are searching for an anonymous user or real users.